# IOT: How to calculate time complexity of an API in cloud IOT Platform

Tags: javascript, performance, rest, ibm-cloud, iot

I would like to determine performance metrics for the API which interacts with IoT Devices hosted in the cloud,  Example I have two option Amazon cloud and IBM cloud for IOT how I determine which one is the best.

1. I have to measure the wait time of REST API which is available in an
   IoT platform. Is there any way I can follow to measure the wait time or performance aspects of the API?
2. Do we have any standard performance benchmarks or metrics which should be evaluated for APIs?

Comment: "Time complexity" is a property of an algorithm, not an API. Are you sure you're using the right term?

Comment: I have to verify the algorithm implemented in javascript to calculate the overall execution time (Request+Response). and what is the best algorithm to implement

Comment: You can certainly measure the time complexity of an API. What the API does is some king of algorithm.

Comment: What is your independent variable? Is it the size of the request? Number of records?

Comment: It sounds like you want [wall time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time) rather than [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

Comment: please provide some example, I am working in javascript.

Comment: what type of sort or search is best, when I am doing a GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of which IoT platform you are referring to. Also not sure if the APIs are communicating through the Messaging infrastructure by adopting MQTT or CoAP.

With respect to AWS IoT Platform you can resort to something like a Simulator infrastructure along with Lambda to achieve your goals to certain extent. Check the article on [Device Simulation with AWS IoT and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/device-simulation-with-aws-iot-and-aws-lambda/). Which could help you.

With respect to performance of API which would deal with your devices you might need to understand the following factors:

- Bandwidth
- Latency
- Scale
- Volume of Devices
- Data/Message size
- Protocol you're adopting

Comment: Check also this article https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2016/10/mqtt-performance-methodology-using.html which is specific to MQTT, but applies to any API.

Comment: @GambitSupport Thank you.